# Max function in C++

Tags: c++, function, vector, max

I once wrote `return max(ds.size(),idx);` where `ds` is a `std::vector` and `idx` is an integer, but it gave me an error saying incompatiable types in the `max` function. I later wrote `int i1 = ds.size() int i2= idx, return max(i1,i2)`, then it worked properly.

can anyone please tell what is the reason behind it ?

Comment: What type does `ds.size()` return?  What type is `idx`?  Are they the same type?

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to `std::max` must have the same type.

`ds.size()` returns a `std::size_t` and unless `idx` can be negative, you should probably make it a `std::size_t` too - or cast to `std::size_t` when using `std::max`:

```cpp
return std::max(ds.size(), static_cast<std::size_t>(idx));
```

Note that if `idx` can be negative, this will likely fail miserably since the cast of a negative value will make it into a positive value, which is likely going to be bigger than `ds.size()`.

Since C++26, you will be able to use [`std::saturate_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/saturate_cast) to clamp the value you cast from to the range of the destination type:

```cpp
return std::max(ds.size(), std::saturate_cast<std::size_t>(idx));
```